# Power set of $\{a,b,c\}$ & $\{a,b,c,d\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble grasping the simple concept of the Power set, especifically of $\{a,b,c\}$

let $A = \{a,b,c\}$

$\mathscr P(A) = \{0, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,c\} \}$

I know that the power set includes the empty set as well and that a power set has $2^n$ elements in the set. Therefore $2^3 = 8$ elements in the set.

What I don't get though is why the response does not include $\{b,a\}$, $\{c,a\}$, $\{c,b\}$?

So if I were to take the power set of $B = \{a,b,c,d\}$ ($16$ elements:

$\mathscr P(B) = \{ 0, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{d\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{a,d\} \{b,c\}, \{b,d\}, \{c,d\}, \{d,c\}, \{d,b\}, \{d,a\}, \{c,b\}, \{c,a\}, \{b,a\}, \{a,b,c,d\} \}$

Why does it have $18$ elements and not $18$?

Thanks!

EDIT: I am missing the three element pairs such as $\{a,b,c\}$. Do you have a strategy or an order to tackle the Power Set? Thanks!

Comment: We consider $\{b,a\}=\{a,b\}$

Comment: so I would be repeating the elements then? the order of the elements inside the pair does not matter?

Comment: @JJ-Dallara Correct. One specifies a set by saying whether each element of the universe of discourse is in the set.

Comment: Basically yes. The set of some elements is the same as the set of a permutation of those elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:** $\{a, b\}, \{b, a\}?$:

In sets, order of writing sets doesn't matter. So, the set $\{x, y, z\}$ is same as $\{y, x, z\}, \{x, z, y\}$ and other 3 orders.

**Question 2:** Strategy for making power sets?

Hint: If a set has $n$ elements, then the power set has $2^n$ sets (including $\{\}$, the empty set. So since $|\{a, b, c, d\}| = 4, $ the power set should have $2^4 = 16$ elements.

Notice how the number $2^n$ comes. For each element, you have option whether to include it, or not (2 possibilities). For $n$ such elements, you get $2^n$ possibilities.

Now, you can start with set of size $0$, this is trivial, it's $\{\} = \emptyset$. Also include the complement, which is the original set itself.

Include all sets of size $1$, they will be the elements themselves. Also include sets of size $n-1$, each will contain all but one element.

Choose 2 elements of set at a time and include them. For each such set, include its complement containing $n-2$ elements.

$\cdots$

Repeat till size of sets is $\lfloor\dfrac{n+1}{2}\rfloor$ and continue adding complements. If $n$ is odd, sets of size $\lfloor\dfrac{n+1}{2}\rfloor$ will have complement sets of size $\lfloor\dfrac{n+1}{2}\rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very detailed response! Clear as water!

Answer (score 0):

the following may also be a useful way of looking at your question.

for a finite set $A$ of cardinality $n$ you may label the elements $a_j$ for $j=0,\dots,n-1$

let $T(n)$ denote the set consisting of the first $2^n$ natural numbers $0,\dots,2^n-1$

let $\mathfrak{P}(A)$ represent the power set of $A$

then we may define a map $\phi:\mathfrak{P}(A) \to T(n)$ by:
$$
\forall B \subset A. \phi(B) =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \chi_B(a_j)2^j
$$
where $\chi_B:B \to \{0,1\}$ is the indicator function for $B$

exercise: show that this map is injective and surjective - i.e. it is a bijection (1-1 correspondence)

$\phi$ therefore has an inverse $\psi:  T(n) \to \mathfrak{P}(A) $
$$
\psi(m) = \{a_j | \beta_m(j)=1\}
$$
where $\beta_m(j)$ returns the $j^\text{th}$ binary digit of $m$ (least significant counted as *zero*$^{\text{th}}$)

this gives a construction for an explicit listing of the elements of $\mathfrak{P}(A) $